# Sharing variables between meteor.call methods in Meteor server

Tags: javascript, meteor

Let's say I have 2 methods declared inside my

```
Meteor.methods({
   firstFunction: function(){
       //makes a http post
       //that returns a value
       //I then get that value and store it in var x
       var x = //value returned from http post
   },

   secondFunction: function(){
       //how do I access the var x?  
   }

});
```

Inside the first function, I make an http post to a website that returns a value.
I can then receive that value and store it inside a variable.
How can I make that variable accessible to the other function e.g. secondFunction  ???

Thank you very much for the help....

Comment: Can `firstFunction` just return `x`?

Comment: hi, it can...but the sequence of events is that i use firstFunction to make a http post call and get a value.  Then site gets redirected to the paypal site...then the paypal site redirects to one of my page again on the site...this new page then calls secondFunction, but within secondFunction I want to access that variable/value in firstFunction e.g. var x.

Comment: What if you store the value in a collection before being redirected?

Comment: Because I don't require users to login before being able to make a purchase, I don't have a good id to use to make the entry unique to this purchase.....the tutorial I was following utilizes Meteor.userid()...but since I don't require users to be logged in, in fact I don't have user login option at all as it stands...I didn't think adding it to the MongoDB database is a good idea.....